# jquery datatable plugin save file as .xls

Tags: jquery, excel, csv, datatables

I am using jquery datatable plugin to show data. I have added the option of file saving as excel,csv and pdf.

Though it is allowing me to save the table content as file. But it saves file as **.csv in both excel and csv case**.

I want to have the excel button to allow me to save file as **.xls format**. How to achieve this in this plugin.

Following is the **code** i am using.

```
$('#datatable_tabletools').dataTable({
            "sDom" : "<'dt-top-row'Tlf>r<'dt-wrapper't><'dt-row dt-bottom-row'<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p>>",
            "aaSorting": [],
            "oTableTools" : {
                "aButtons" : ["copy", "print", {
                    "sExtends" : "collection",
                    "sButtonText" : 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                    "aButtons" : ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }],
                "sSwfPath" : "<?=$baseUrl?>static/js/plugin/datatables/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            "fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json) {
                $(this).closest('#dt_table_tools_wrapper').find('.DTTT.btn-group').addClass('table_tools_group').children('a.btn').each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('btn-sm btn-default');
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. You have to use the `"sFileName"` property.

To achieve your goal, specify `"sFileName": "*.xls"` for the Excel export.

Here is your code adapted like you want:

```
$('#datatable_tabletools').dataTable({
    "sDom" : "<'dt-top-row'Tlf>r<'dt-wrapper't><'dt-row dt-bottom-row'<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p>>",
    "aaSorting": [],
    "oTableTools" : {
        "aButtons" : ["copy", "print", {
            "sExtends" : "collection",
            "sButtonText" : 'Save <span class="caret" />',
            "aButtons" : ["csv", {
                        "sExtends": "xls",
                        "sFileName": "*.xls",
                        "bFooter": false
                    }, "pdf"]
        }],
        "sSwfPath" : "<?=$baseUrl?>static/js/plugin/datatables/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    },
    "fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json) {
        $(this).closest('#dt_table_tools_wrapper').find('.DTTT.btn-group').addClass('table_tools_group').children('a.btn').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('btn-sm btn-default');
        });
    }
});
```